# Access props and state of current component in React JS within an event handler

Tags: javascript, highcharts, reactjs

I am using Highcharts.js in conjunction with React.js. I want to re-render the view when a user clicks a point in Highcharts. To do this, I need to access the props variable *in the click handler*. Normally, I would just use `this.props` to update the props, but this won't work in an event handler. Therefore, how do I access the current component as a variable in the event handler so I can access its props? Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

My `config` variable for HighCharts looks something like this. To clarify, this code is coming from the `render` function of the same component.

```
var config = {
      ...
      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              cursor: 'pointer',
              point: {
                  events: {
                      click: function (event) {
                        //the `this` variable does not have props or state here
                        //`this` refers to the point object on the graph here
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      },
    };
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wouldn't triggering a `rerender` event from inside the click event handler make more sense? `events: { click: myRerenderFunction }`

Comment: You can call a function defined above the scope of the event that handles the rerendering for you. If you define it at the same level as say the `config` variable it should act as a closure and be accessible inside the event. I bet this is isn't the only place a re-render event will have to be called anyways.

Comment: That's a great idea, but how would I pass in the point object itself (the `e` object, if you will) into `myRerenderFunction` so I could access it in the custom function?

Comment: exactly the same way `function myRerenderFunction(e) { /* do something */ }` Hang on, making it an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the click handler function somewhere outside the config variable, and it should have access to everything outside the scope of the event.

```
myRerenderFunction(e) { /* do something */ } // define function here...

var config = {
      ...
          events: {
              click: myRerenderFunction // ...and it's accessible since they're defined in the same scope
          }
    };
```

Or you could just put the rerendering itself outside the click handler.

```
myRerenderFunction(e) { /* do something */ } // This is now a closure...

var config = {
      ...
          events: {
              click: function(e) {
                  /* Do something with the event */
                  myRerenderFunction(e); // ...which means you can access it from inside the click handler function
              }
          }
    };
```

Or you could just store the current `this` as a closure.

```
var whateverScopeThisIs = this;

var config = {
      ...
          events: {
              click: function(e) {
                  /* Do something with the event */
                  whateverScopeThisIs.doSomething(e);
              }
          }
    };
```

You've got plenty of options, something along those lines should work.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I decided to go with the first option. Just to clarify, I did have to prepend the method call with "this" as the javascript compiler does not recognize the function, so it should be: `click: this.myRerenderfunction`

Comment: That's because you created it as a method like `this.myRerenderfunction = function(e) { }`. If you had created it as a regular function as per the above #1 and #2 you wouldn't have needed to. There's nothing wrong with it being a method, I'm just explaining what's going on. :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
events: {
   click: function (event) {
       window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event)
   }
}
```