# Why can't I access state and props inside event handler

Tags: reactjs

I have written this code

```
import React from 'react';
import DimensionPickerAction from '../actions/DimensionPickerActions.js';
import MovieLensAppStore from '../stores/MovieLensAppStore.js';

class DimensionPicker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dimensionName: this.props.dimension,
            items: MovieLensAppStore.getAttributes(this.props.dimension),
            currentItem : MovieLensAppStore.getCurrentAttribute(this.props.dimension)
        };
    }

    onSelectionChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        DimensionPickerAction.selectionChange(temp.state.dimensionName, event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        var optionNodes = this.state.items.map((item) => {
            return(<option key={item.id} value={item.val}>{item.val}</option>)
        });
        return(<div><select onChange={this.onSelectionChange} defaultValue={this.state.currentItem}>{optionNodes}</select></div>);
    }

}

export default DimensionPicker;
```

I can see that when the method `onSelectionChange` get called both the state and props are null.

I found this thread which discusses the same issue

[Access props and state of current component in React JS within an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274658/access-props-and-state-of-current-component-in-react-js-within-an-event-handler)

But the solution does not work for me. I tried to create another method which is then called from `onSelectionChange` but that method is also not visible to the event handler.

I also tried to store the this pointer in a temp variable ... but that leads to a syntax error.

Does anyone know how to access state and props inside event handler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of React .14 event handlers are not being auto-bound to the scope of the component.

You can use the dirty .bind(this) method which I hate and it's slow like so.

```
render() {
    var optionNodes = this.state.items.map((item) => {
        return(<option key={item.id} value={item.val}>{item.val}</option>)
    });
    return(<div><select onChange={this.onSelectionChange.bind(this)} defaultValue={this.state.currentItem}>{optionNodes}</select></div>);
}
```

Or use fat arrow functions to wrap the callback in, this is much faster and does not require binding scope since fat arrow function execute on the scope the where created.

```
render() {
    var optionNodes = this.state.items.map((item) => {
        return(<option key={item.id} value={item.val}>{item.val}</option>)
    });
    return(<div><select onChange={(event) => { this.onSelectionChange(event) }} defaultValue={this.state.currentItem}>{optionNodes}</select></div>);
}
```

Comment: It wasn't a React 0.14 change. Components that extend `React.Component` (introduced in 0.13) never had auto-binding. Components constructed with `React.createClass()` still have auto-binding. I've previously documented this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505511/runtime-context-this-of-the-function-comes-from-this-props/34505757#34505757

Comment: Ha. I stand corrected! Version tracking is not my strong suit! Considering the benefit and general direction to move away from .createClass seems like my answer still hold true.

Comment: Or you can bind the functions on the classes constructor like this this.functionName = this.functionName.bind(this);